# How to recreate the orders context in order to send out emails in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

I am creating a console task to ship orders based on XML files ([How to add a shipment (tracking code + change status to shipped) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462433/how-to-add-a-shipment-tracking-code-change-status-to-shipped-programmaticall)
) which I import.

Currently I am using

```
$context = Context::createDefaultContext();
```

And create a shipment:

```
    $this->deliveryRepository->update([
        [
            'id' => $deliveryId,
            'trackingCodes' => [$trackingCode]
        ]
    ], $context);

    $context->addExtension(
        MailSendSubscriber::MAIL_CONFIG_EXTENSION,
        new MailSendSubscriberConfig(false)
    );

    $this->orderService->orderDeliveryStateTransition(
        $deliveryId,
        'ship',
        new ParameterBag(),
        $context
    );
```

This does not send out the shipment confirmation mail.

I am assuming the reason is, because I am in the default context.

Can I / should I recreate the context from the Storefront where the order was placed in? How does this work?
(maybe using `\Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\BaseContextFactory::create` ? but this is tagged as `@internal` )

Or is it okay to use the default context here (see [Shopware 6 get context in scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688135/shopware-6-get-context-in-scheduled-task)) and is the problem something else?

EDIT:

```
$context = $this->baseContextFactory->create($order->getSalesChannelId())->getContext();
```

does work, but I still do not receive emails.

EDIT2:

The mail problem is unrelated - I am testing this with an Unit test and it does not seem to send out mails in general. This it out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\OrderConverter` service to assemble a `SalesChannelContext` based on an order. You can then get the `Context` from the `SalesChannelContext`.

```php
$salesChannelContext = $this->orderConverter->assembleSalesChannelContext($order, Context::createDefaultContext());
$context = $salesChannelContext->getContext();
```

Comment: Perfect - unfortunately it does not solve me email problem, but maybe that's better suited in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462433/how-to-add-a-shipment-tracking-code-change-status-to-shipped-programmaticall

Comment: Mail problem seems to be due to unit testing, edited the question.